# Intersection of two 4D hyperspheres

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces, spheres

In 3D, consider a large sphere (radius $d$) with a smaller sphere (radius $r$) centered on the
large sphere's surface.  It's surprising that the large sphere's surface covered by the small
sphere has area $\pi r^2$, exactly, regardless of $d$.

In 2D, there is no simple relationship like this.  The large circle's covered arc length
is $2d\cdot\sin^{-1}{(r/d\cdot\sqrt{(1-r^2/4/d^2)})}$.

What about 4D?  To reiterate, I'd like to know the "3D surface area" covered on a large
sphere by a smaller sphere (centered on the large sphere's surface).  If there is no simple
analytic form, I'd like a first-order correction to the large $d$ limit of $4\pi r^3/3$
(of the large sphere's total $2\pi^2d^3$ surface area).

Comment: Can you cite or derive your original claim?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Areas_of_intersecting_spheres